# can't get mysql query to output user and count at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, count

I'm new at mysql queries so forgive me if I'm missing something stupid.
I have a table called marketeers with fields id, user, site, link, ip.
People click on different links on my site and it gathers info about the ip addresses and the user who made the link etc so I can determine which link performs best.

I want it to count the unique ip's that a link has and then display the user, counted unique links, and the link itself.

It almost works except it won't display the user. Here is the code.

Thanks for any help...

Dan

```
$query = "SELECT link, COUNT(DISTINCT(ip)) FROM marketeers GROUP BY link ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT(ip))";

// Execute the query
$result = mysql_query( $query );
echo $result;
echo "<br><br>";
if (!$result){
die ("Could not query the database: <br />". mysql_error( ));
}
else{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "{$row['user']} ".
    "{$row[count('ip')]}  " .
         "{$row['link']}<br><br> ";
}   

 }
}
```

Comment: You want for every link, all users that hit that link?

Answer (score 3):

You're not selecting the user field from your database. You're fetching two fields only. 'link', and the count of IPs. Try this:

```
SELECT link, COUNT(DISTINCT(ip)) as cnt, user FROM ...
```

and then

```
echo "{$row['user']} {'$row['cnt']} {$row['link']}<br />";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not asking for the user, so it's logical it's not there :)

try:

```
SELECT user, link, COUNT(DISTINCT(ip)) FROM ....
```